# Cycling through jquery object to get its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object

I have to loop through the object and get all its values. Here's an image of object [image]
So, basically i have to get classificatorCodeId and loop through observationList to get its child classificatorCodeId's and observationLists, and so on.
If you guys have any ideas, what's the best way to loop through this object, id be happy to try your solutions.

Comment: I've tried different solutions of $.each(obj, function()). Inside the main $.each, there were more than 6 other loops and then i got confused. I think i have to use methods like hasOwnAttribute or find?

Comment: The end effect should be a list of values? Or some sort of map?

Comment: @Üllar So show us what have you tried. Post your code

Comment: I'm trying to reach the most inner classificatorCodeId-s and its value-s. For example. id=2604 has two child objects(2624 and 2629). i have to loop through 2624 childs and assign id=2641 and value=4 to different variables.

Comment: As @IanBrindley said you should try recursion. Write a function that checks whether the observation given in argument has a value, if it has return it (possibily with ID), otherwise use the same function to get the values from each observation in the observation list.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print all values in that object as key --> value pairs

```
var traverse = function(mainObject)
{
  $.each(mainObject, function(index, subObject)
  {
    if(($.type(subObject) === "object" || $.type(subObject) === "array"))
    {
      traverse(subObject);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log(index+" --> "+subObject);
    }
  });
}

traverse(mainObject);
```